# Yii: Adding A Textfield Filter to CListview using Ajax and Jquery

Tags: jquery, yii, yii-components

I am a Yii Beginner and I am currently working on adding an Ajax filter to CListView where I followed the Steps displayed in this [Tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/185/clistview-ajax-filtering/)

Basicaly when I intialise the $issue_nr in the altered IssueController/Index action the filter works perfectly, but for some reason ther $_Get variables are not being passed through the submit button!

I have been searching for a while, and this has been driving me crazy because I feel I have missed a very simple step!

Any Help or advices of any kind are deeply appreciated!

Where my Index Action is:

```
public function actionIndex($issue_nr=NULL)
    {     
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    if (strlen($issue_nr) > 0)
        $criteria->addSearchCondition('issue_nr_fk', $issue_nr, true);
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Issue', array('criteria' => $criteria,));
    $this->render('index', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider));
    }
```

And in Views/Issues/Index

```
     <div class="row">

<?php

  echo CHtml::beginForm(CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('Issue/index')), 'get', array('id'=>'filter-form'))
  . CHtml::textField('string', (isset($_GET['string'])) ? $_GET['string'] : '', array('id'=>'issue_nr'))
  . CHtml::submitButton('Search', array('submit' => array('Issue/index', 'id'=>$_GET['string'])))
  . CHtml::endForm();

 //JQUERY FUNCTION TO REDUCE DBQUERIES
 Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search',
      "var ajaxUpdateTimeout;
       var ajaxRequest;
       $('input#issue_nr_fk').keyup(function(){
       ajaxRequest = $(this).serialize();
       clearTimeout(ajaxUpdateTimeout);
       ajaxUpdateTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
       $.fn.yiiListView.update(

    // this is the id of the CListView
       'ajaxListView',
       {data: ajaxRequest}
       )
      },
    // this is the delay
         300);
        });"
       );
     ?>
 </div>

 <?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_view',
    'sortableAttributes'=>array('issue_nr_fk',
    'c_date'),
    'id'=>'ajaxListView',
     ));
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right, you're setting form action as "CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('Issue/index')" without any "get" parameters, that's why you don't receive them in controller.
Use an empty string for action - the form will be submitted to current page url with all parameters present.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!!
you mean it should look something like this?

 CHtml::beginForm(CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('', '')), 'get', array('id'=>'filter-form'))
    . CHtml::textField('issue', (isset($_GET['issue'])) ? $_GET['issue'] : '', array('id'=>'issue_nr'))
    . CHtml::submitButton('Search', array('submit' => array('Issue/index')))
    . CHtml::endForm();

I am receiving an output link in this format:
http://localhost/Sys/index.php?r=Issue%2Findex&0=&issue=10

Any advice or pointers are greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: I think I somehow got it working by adding this to the IndexAction :
 if(isset($_GET['issue']))
        {
            $issue_nr=$_GET['issue'];
        }